# What's the difference between these two kinds of rootSaga config

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

the code below is a trial of the rootSaga in redux-saga

Could anyone tell me the difference?

```js
// kind 1
export default function* rootProjectSaga (): IterableIterator<any> {  
  yield all([
    takeEvery(TRANSFER_PROJECT, transferProject as any),
    takeLatest(LOAD_PROJECTS, getProjects as any)    
  ])
}
```

```js
// kind 2
export default function* rootProjectSaga (): IterableIterator<any> { 
  yield  takeEvery(TRANSFER_PROJECT, transferProject as any)
  yield  takeLatest(LOAD_PROJECTS, getProjects as any)   
}
```

```js
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)
sagaMiddleware.run(rootProjectSaga)
```

Comment: My requirement is that after TRANSFER_PROJECT, I will LOAD_PROJECTS.
But with the code of kind 1,I find the order of the execution can not be ensured

Answer (score 2):

```
export default function* rootProjectSaga (): IterableIterator<any> { 
  yield takeEvery(TRANSFER_PROJECT, transferProject as any)
  yield takeLatest(LOAD_PROJECTS, getProjects as any)   
}
```

This code will listen for every TRANSFER_PROJECT that ever happens, and call transferProject when it does. The second line of the saga is never reached, because takeEvery never completes.

```
export default function* rootProjectSaga (): IterableIterator<any> {  
  yield all([
    takeEvery(TRANSFER_PROJECT, transferProject as any),
    takeLatest(LOAD_PROJECTS, getProjects as any)    
  ])
}
```

This code will fork two effects to run in parallel. The former will listen for every TRANSFER_PROJECT, the latter will listen for every LOAD_PROJECTS. The two effects are unrelated to eachother, and transferProject and getProjects will be called in whatever order the actions occur.

> My requirement is that after TRANSFER_PROJECT, I will LOAD_PROJECTS.

If you mean you want to wait for a TRANSFER_PROJECT action, then run transferProject, then wait for LOAD_PROJECTS, then run getProjects, that can be done like this:

```
export default function* rootProjectSaga () {  
  const transferAction = yield take(TRANSFER_PROJECT);
  yield call(transferProject, transferAction);
  const loadAction = yield take(LOAD_PROJECTS);
  yield call(getProjects, loadAction);   
}
```

Be aware that the above code will not notice any LOAD_PROJECTS actions that happen before TRANSFER_PROJECT, nor any TRANSFER_PROJECT actions that happen while waiting for LOAD_PROJECTS.

Additionally, if you want this to happen more than once, you'll need to wrap it in a loop:

```
export default function* rootProjectSaga () {  
  while (true) {
    const transferAction = yield take(TRANSFER_PROJECT);
    yield call(transferProject, transferAction);
    const loadAction = yield take(LOAD_PROJECTS);
    yield call(getProjects, loadAction);   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, the exact context I use the rootSaga is as above, i dont know the diffenrence. can you hunt me down,- -!